# How to fix errors for Django's Auth/CustomUser after resetting the migrations and db?

Tags: django, github-actions, customizer

After experimenting with setting up CustomUser and many-to-many relationships, I decided to make some (what turned out to be major) changes to the models. I had read that CustomUser/Auth needs to be set up first, or else it'll be a mess. But since I'm just learning and there was barely any data involved, I just went for it--not to mess up the CustomUser model intentionally, but I changed a model name--and (maybe this is the critical error) I updated the names everywhere it appeared. Now I'd deleted and reset the database, VENV folder, all the migration (along with `__pycache__`) files, and recreated test data so many times that I thought I could download the GitHub repo and set up a fresh new app easily again. But the app refuses to run and keeps asking for a missing table.

Re-creating the app isn't my main concern-I'd like to understand what happened-what is this missing table (see the snippet of the error code)? AND: Why is a perfectly intact repo having the same issue with the missing table?

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Volume2/dev/lms6-v2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Volumes/Volume2/dev/lms6-v2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_staff
```

The app is called `accounts` and the CustomUser models are:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "HOD"), (2, "Staff"), (3, "Student"))
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=user_type_data)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class AdminHOD(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = "Staff"
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.admin.first_name + " " + self.admin.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('staff_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Make sure you have migrations folder in each apps and it have __init__.py files in those folders.

Comment: Yes, the `init.py` files are there.

Comment: have you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: @Mark2 Yes, that's why it puzzled me--when the db, migration and VENV files are all gone, why is there still issues with missing tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all u need to delete all your migrations files(sure u have ) and the (**pycache**) ...

After you have done that dont just run  makemigration u have to be logical with it

1. run python manage.py makemigrations <app_name:the app that contains the AUTH_USER_MODEL>
2. run python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> but this time u decide what app comes next in the way u wrote ur models they makemigrations in that order'
   3)run python manage.py makemigrations
   4)lastly run  python manage.py migrations

... this how i solved this issue anytime i run into this problems

Answer (score 0):

Obviously messing with the CustomUser model in Django isn't to be attempted casually, but this was a good learning experience. So for the newly initiated accidentally stuck at the same spot, the answer by Ogechuwku Matthew is a good start.

To elaborate-this is what I did:

1. Deleted all the migration files, including files in `__pycache__` (EXCEPT for the `__init__` file(s).
2. Disabled the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyCustomUser'` line in `settings.py` This step is key.
3. Removed (or commented out) all but the most essential files.
4. Commented out all but the `CustomUser` model and models extended from it.
5. Ran `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` and then 'python manage.py migrate`
6. After step 4 worked, ran `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` and `python manage.py migrate` again.
7. Moved the rest of the files back in, starting with the simplest bits, like 'HomeView' in `views.py` and 'home.html'.
8. When the app started up with 'home.html', un-commented models, views, and urls one cluster at a time.

Additionally: If error occur when running the app, first check the embedded dynamic links--they may `extend` or `include` files that aren't there yet-same with `{% load static %}`